# Removing values that repeat more than 5 times in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas to work with csv files. I need to remove a few repeated values  if they occur consecutively. 
I understand there is a duplicate function that removes any value that repeats the second time irrespective of where they occur. 
But I have to remove the data only if the values of a column repeat for more than 5 consecutive rows. 
For example,

```
     1
     1
     3
     1 
     1
     1
     1
     1
     2
```

Here I don't want to remove the two 1's at the top in B but only the 1's that repeat for 5 times successively.
Any pointers as to how I should go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>> df = pd.Series([1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2])
>> df.groupby((df.shift() != df).cumsum())\
     .filter(lambda x: len(x) < 5)
0    1
1    1
2    3
8    2
```

Comment: It works. Thanks! Is there any restriction on extending this to say a dataframe or a column in a dataframe? Any particular reason you are creating a series to do this?

Comment: It should work the same. There is no practical difference between a Series or a column in a DataFrame. I used a Series for simplicity in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Showing how answer by **elyase** also works for DataFrame (not Series).

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,2]]).transpose(),columns = ["col"])
>> df.groupby((df["col"].shift() != df["col"]).cumsum()).filter(lambda x: len(x) < 5)
    col
 0    1
 1    1
 2    3
 8    2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.assign(col2=df1.col1.astype(int).diff().ne(0).cumsum()).sql().count("col1","","over(partition by col2) col3","*").filter("col3<5").order("index").select("col1")

┌─────────┐
│  col1   │
│ varchar │
├─────────┤
│ 1       │
│ 1       │
│ 3       │
│ 2       │
└─────────┘
```