# Delete all columns for which value repents consecutively more than 3 times

Tags: python, pandas

I have a`df` that looks like this:

| date | stock1 | stock2 | stock3 | stock4 | stock5 | stock6 | stock7 | stock8 | stock9 | stock10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/20 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | 0.1 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 12/20 | 0.1 | 0.6 | 0.9 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.1 |
| 10/20 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.9 | 0.1 |
| 12/20 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.9 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.1 |
| 10/20 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.7 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.9 |
| 11/20 | 0.8 | 0.9 | 0.3 | 0.4 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.3 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 12/20 | 0.3 | 0.6 | 0.9 | 0.5 | 0.6 | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.9 | 0.1 |

I want to delete all columns for which the same value repeats, consecutively, more than 3 times. In this example,  the columns "stock1", "stock6" and "stock9" should be deleted. In the other columns, we have repeating values more than 3 times, but not one after the other.
I think I can adapt the code from that question [Removing values that repeat more than 5 times in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109256/removing-values-that-repeat-more-than-5-times-in-pandas-dataframe), but I could not manage to do that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set "date" aside as index, then check if the rows are different from the next one as use it to `groupby`+`cumcount`.

Then compute the max count per column, if greater than N-1, drop the column:

```
df2 = df.set_index('date')
N = 3
df2.loc[:, df2.apply(lambda c: c.groupby(c.ne(c.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()).max().lt(N-1)]
```

output:

```
        stock2   stock3   stock4   stock5   stock7   stock8   stock10
date                                                                 
10/20       0.2      0.3      0.4      0.5      0.7      0.8      0.9
11/20       0.9      0.3      0.4      0.3      0.3      0.2      0.1
12/20       0.6      0.9      0.5      0.6      0.8      0.7      0.1
10/20       0.2      0.3      0.4      0.5      0.7      0.8      0.9
11/20       0.9      0.3      0.4      0.3      0.3      0.2      0.1
12/20       0.6      0.9      0.5      0.6      0.8      0.7      0.1
10/20       0.2      0.3      0.4      0.5      0.7      0.8      0.9
11/20       0.9      0.3      0.4      0.3      0.3      0.2      0.1
12/20       0.6      0.9      0.5      0.6      0.8      0.7      0.1
```

intermediate count of successive values:

```
>>> df2.apply(lambda c: c.groupby(c.ne(c.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount())

        stock1   stock2   stock3   stock4   stock5   stock6   stock7   stock8   stock9   stock10
date                                                                                            
10/20         0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
11/20         1        0        1        1        0        0        0        0        0        0
12/20         2        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1
10/20         3        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0
11/20         0        0        1        1        0        0        0        0        2        0
12/20         0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        3        1
10/20         0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        4        0
11/20         0        0        1        1        0        2        0        0        0        0
12/20         0        0        0        0        0        3        0        0        0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could want avoid apply here:

```
N = 3
df.loc[:, 
   df.set_index('date')
     .ne(df.shift()).cumsum()
     .stack()
     .groupby(level=1)
     .value_counts()
     .max(level=0).le(N)]
```

Comment: that drops too many columns ;)

Comment: Yes, now it should work like mine, except using `stack`/`groupby` in place of `apply` ;)

Comment: I think groupby inside apply can be slow @mozway

Comment: not always, especially since the `apply` is on columns here (not rows). wisely used apply is sometimes faster, one would need to check on the dataset

Comment: I think stack() + groupby() is faster always...
The bigger the dataframe and the more columns, the worse @mozway

Answer (score 0):

```
df1[['date']].join(
    df1.iloc[:,1:].loc[:,df1.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda ss:(ss.diff()!=0).cumsum().value_counts().max())<3]
)
    
    
     date  stock2  stock3  stock4  stock5  stock7  stock8  stock10
0  10/20     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.5     0.7     0.8      0.9
1  11/20     0.9     0.3     0.4     0.3     0.3     0.2      0.1
2  12/20     0.6     0.9     0.5     0.6     0.8     0.7      0.1
3  10/20     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.5     0.7     0.8      0.9
4  11/20     0.9     0.3     0.4     0.3     0.3     0.2      0.1
5  12/20     0.6     0.9     0.5     0.6     0.8     0.7      0.1
6  10/20     0.2     0.3     0.4     0.5     0.7     0.8      0.9
7  11/20     0.9     0.3     0.4     0.3     0.3     0.2      0.1
8  12/20     0.6     0.9     0.5     0.6     0.8     0.7      0.1
```